# Chat application how to generate an id for a particular chat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, chat

Let's say I have two users, "Matt" & "Kevin". Matt wants to message Kevin, by clicking a chat button to send Kevin a direct message a chat box boots up, he sends a message and Kevin receives it.

I generate the chat id by taking the person who sent it (Matt) and the person who received the message (Kevin) and concatenating it into an id.

```
var me = "Matt";
var user = "Kevin";
var uniqueChatID = me+user;
```

As I save the message server side (with mongoDB) the message object has a `chatID` of `MattKevin`. So now when I want to get back to that chat I can pull in all messages with the `chatID` of `MattKevin`.

This works fine, until Kevin wants to boot up a chat with Matt, then the id becomes `KevinMatt`. Now I am referencing a different chat, it's backwards. So If I want to pass `uniqueChatID` to get the messages it will pull a different set.

```
var me = "Kevin";
var user = "Matt";
var uniqueChatID = me+user;
```

So I am curious how can I set this up a bit better so that my program knows, ok Matt and Kevin have a chat, so if Matt messages Kevin it pulls in their chat or visa versa, Kevin messages Matt and it gets the same messages?

Comment: Sort them alphabetically?

Comment: Ok, so client side generate the ID by alphabetic letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort them alphabetically:

```
var me = "Kevin";
var user = "Matt";
var uniqueChatID = [me, user].sort().join('');
```

That said, while this technically works, I'd recommend you do a little housekeeping - ensure they're always lowercase, and ensure on your db that you enforce unique usernames. Or, I'd even suggest giving the user a unique identifier (like a UUID) and use *that* instead to create the UCID:

```
var me = CurrentUser.uuid(); // 8cb3ebb8-30f9-11e5-a151-feff819cdc9f
var targetUser = Chat.targetUser(); // Matt: 9bc1ef9c-6719-4041-afd3-c5b87c90690d
var uniqueChatID = [me, targetUser].sort().join(',');
// 8cb3ebb8-30f9-11e5-a151-feff819cdc9f,9bc1ef9c-6719-4041-afd3-c5b87c90690d
```

And lastly, if your db supports relationships or connections, your best option is to separate chat table/collection for each chat and "connect" (or create a relationship) between both users and the chat. Then the next time you go and load it up, the connection will lead you to a unique chat that's connected to both users.

Comment: Very interesting, cool man. Never thought of that, good idea :)

Comment: This is not going to be unique for large application.

Comment: Yeah it is, because it's not really as arbitrary as Kevin or Matt, its by their nickname, which is unique.

Comment: Where does `CurrentUser` && `Chat` come from?

Comment: Oh, that was just a pseudo code suggesting that you might have a class singleton that represents of them. Might as easily be a variable too.

Comment: I think that approach has several problems. First, there simply is no reason to create an artificial ID for an user: they already are uniquely identified by their respective `_id`, regardless of said `_id`'s cardinality. Furthermore, it introduces an unneeded layer of abstraction, eliminating the possibility to do easy checks from the MongoDB shell *without* introducing an advantage, as described above.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg hence my primary recommendation is to create a separate table for chats and create a relationship between the users and the chat row.

Comment: @remus There are no real relations in MongoDB. You'd have to do manual JOINs. Hence my critique to your solution. See my answer for a MongoDB specific solution, which admittedly was only mentioned in the tags of the question.

Comment: I do something similar when working with Cassandra. [This is the doc for Mongo](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents), which I'm sure you're familiar with is what I'm talking about. That said, your answer works just as well - toss the messages straight into the table and return them via query. Only problem with that, is it entirely secure with everyone's messages being in one giant table?

Comment: @remus Is it in any database? ;) Object permission  checking should _always_ be done explicitly in a service layer anyway, even when using the principals unique identified as the query parameter, right? Personally, I tend to use some sort of filter in the service layer on the result sets, returning only those results the principal is eligible to access, which might be `null`, preventing both horizontal and vertical privilege escalation if done properly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you approach is too complex. Furthermore, it looks like you want to embed the individual chat messages into the document bearing the created `_id`. The problem here is that there is a [16 MB size limit on BSON documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit) at the time of this writing. Upon reaching this limit, your users simply could not communicate any more. Increasing the size of documents may also lead to frequent [document relocations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-operations/#document-growth), which is a *very* costly operation unless you use the new WiredTiger storage engine introduced in version 3.0 of MongoDB.

So we need a more scalable approach.

Here is how I would do it:

User:

```
{
  _id: "Kevin",
  email: "kevin@example.com"
  /* Put further user details as you see fit*/
}
```

Message:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  from: "Kevin",
  /* You might want to have multi-person chats, hence the array */
  to: ["Matt"],
  ts: new ISODate(),
  message: "Hi, Matt!"
}
```

Index:

```
db.messages.ensureIndex({from:1,to:1,ts:1})
```

Query for reconstructing all messages a user received:

```
var user = "Matt"
db.messages.find({"to": user}).sort({ts:1})
```

Now you can iterate over the result set and open a chat window for each "from" you find.

Query for reconstructing a defined chat

```
var user = "Matt"
var sender = "Kevin"
db.messages.find({"from": sender, "to":user}).sort({ts:1})
```

will give you all messages sent to Matt by Kevin, ordered by time. Since both queries should utilize the index, they should be pretty fast. You can use `.limit(x)` to query only the last x messages sent to `user`.

With this approach, you don't need an artificial `_id`, the index created allows you to do every query related to the participants efficiently and the messages can be sorted in order. Because each message is saved individually and does not change any more, you can store an almost indefinite number of messages and bypass the document relocation problem.

Comment: Very cool man, thanks for sharing, I had a discussion with a friend and he recommended an approach similar to this.

I don't see how my approach is to complex, or intensive? I am utilizing sockets, so when the socket data hits the server it stores the data then sends the data to you via sockets.

If you and me chat all our messages are stored eitherway, right. Each message has a `chatID`, when the page refreshes and you want to get back to the chat, it just gets all the messages with that `chatID` you and me generated.

Let me really analyze what you are saying here, so I can understand.